# Problema na organização dos dados de um ListView - BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview

estou com um probleminha na hora de organizar os dados pessoais de um banco externo MySql.
Tipo, criei uma classe InfoPessoaisAdapter herdando de BaseAdapter onde eu pego nome, endereco, bairro, cep, telefone e observações. Eu joguei na listview da seguinte maneira:

```
List<InfoPessoais> dadosPessoais = new ArrayList<InfoPessoais>();
    InfoPessoais ip = new InfoPessoais();

    for (String k : dados) {
        ip = new InfoPessoais();
        ip.setNome(k);
        ip.setEndereco(k);
        ip.setBairro(k);
        ip.setCep(k);
        ip.setTelefone(k);
        ip.setObs(k);
        dadosPessoais.add(ip);
    }
    lvInformacoesPessoais.setAdapter(new InfoPessoaisAdapter(this, dadosPessoais));
```

O problema é que na hora de mostrar na tela do meu aparelho, ele mostra o nome repetidamente para todos os campos, dai o proximo campo repete novamente e assim por diante... ele fica tudo errado como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

dados:

```
try{
        respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(url, parametrosPost);
        String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
        resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        Log.i("Informações", "Informações: "+resposta);

        char separador = '#';
        int contadados = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < resposta.length(); i++){
            if (separador == resposta.charAt(i)){
                contadados++;
                dados = new String[contadados];
            }
        }

        char caracterLido = resposta.charAt(0);
        String nome = "";

        for (int i=0; caracterLido != '^'; i++){
            caracterLido = resposta.charAt(i);
            Log.i("Chars", "Chars do Paciente"+caracterLido);

            if (caracterLido != '#'){
                if (caracterLido == '*'){
                    nome = nome + " ";
                }else
                nome+= (char) caracterLido;

            }else{
                Log.i("Nome", "Nome: "+nome);
                dados[posicao] =""+ nome;
                Log.i("Nome posição ["+posicao+"]", ""+dados[posicao]);
                posicao = posicao + 1;
                nome = "";
            }
        }
        Log.i("Fim", "Fim do for");

    }catch(Exception erro){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Erro: "+erro, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: na sua classe `InfoPessoais` foi feito o `@Override` do método `ToString()`?

Comment: Pra falar a verdade eu nem tenho esse método ToString()

Comment: String k : dados no for tu ta setando todos os campos com o valor de k... por logica os campos vão sair repetidos

Comment: oque você exatamente quer mostrar?

Comment: no seu caso, sempre possui o valor de k

Comment: tu tem q fazer algo assim...  ip.setNome(dados.getitem(i).getNome()); esse getitem  é só um exemplo pra poder item na posicao i.

Comment: mostre como vc fez a classe "dados" no String k : dados.

Comment: melhor explicando qual classe pertence a variavel dados? mostre como vc implementou essa classe na sua pergunta seria uma boa.

Comment: @PedroRangel o dados é tudo que eu to buscando do meu arquivo php, que contem todos os campos que eu necessito...

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi como que eu faria para não setar sempre o k? não posso deixar que repita tudo...

Comment: o @PedroRangel disse ali, mas agora que você postou o código todo, vamos dar uma olhada

Comment: Sim, mas pela variavel dados, não consigo puxar nada daquilo... é apenas um String[] onde eu armazenei todos os dados do php

Comment: os dados estão vindo em que ordem? estão todos sequenciais dentro de dados[] ?? preciso saber como está o vetor dados depois de obter os valores.

Comment: Sim, nome, endereço e etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao invés de fazer o seguinte código :

```
for (String k : dados) {
    ip = new InfoPessoais();
    ip.setNome(k);
    ip.setEndereco(k);
    ip.setBairro(k);
    ip.setCep(k);
    ip.setTelefone(k);
    ip.setObs(k);
    dadosPessoais.add(ip);
}
```

Faz o seguinte:

```
int i = 0;
while(i < dados.length)
{
    ip = new InfoPessoais();
    ip.setNome(dados[i++]);
    ip.setEndereco(dados[i++]);
    ip.setBairro(dados[i++]);
    ip.setCep(dados[i++]);
    ip.setTelefone(dados[i++]);
    ip.setObs(dados[i++]);
    dadosPessoais.add(ip);
}
```

Isso é muito inviável de se fazer, mas por enquanto pra resolver seu problema, isso já basta.

Comment: boaa, funcionou perfeitamente...
Obrigadoo...